# How can I obtain the instance of the default ReactiveAuthenticationManager implementation?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm declaring the SecurityWebFilterChain as below:

```
  @Bean
  protected SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
            "/actuator/**",
            "/v3/api-docs.yaml",
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers(
            "/blabla/**")
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oAuth2ResourceServerSpec -> {
          oAuth2ResourceServerSpec.jwt(
              jwtSpec -> jwtSpec.jwkSetUri(
                  oAuthServerUrl.concat("/realms/"
                      .concat(oAuthServerRealm)
                      .concat("/protocol/openid-connect/certs"))));
          oAuth2ResourceServerSpec
              .bearerTokenConverter(new ServerBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter())
              .jwt();
        });
    return http.build();
  }
```

So, as it can be seen, I'm not declaring any implementation of the ReactiveAuthenticationManager. This is provided there by default from Spring. Now, I want to use this impl in a custom web filter so that there I can manually do the authentication but there is not spring bean which implements the ReactiveAuthenticationManager interface. Is there any way to get the default implementation of ReactiveAuthenticationManager as a bean in Spring Boot. I'm using Spring WebFlux.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. There are several classes implementing the interface. Why not just autowire it? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/ReactiveAuthenticationManager.html